# Every possible QFT from positive geometry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, geometry, theory-of-everything, amplituhedron

Physicist Nima Arkani-Hamed has taken an interesting approach to understand fundamental physics based on geometry (specifically, positive geometry constructions). This started with his work with Jaroslav Trnka in the amplituhedron [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2007) and later it was generalised to the associahedron [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11764),the EFT-hedron [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.15849)...

I was reading an interesting presentation made by one of Arkani-Hamed's collaborators (Yu-Tin Huang) titled "Inside the walls of positive geometry: the space of consistent QFTs" [4](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/stringsmirrors/2018/107.pdf) based on recent work done by Arkani-Hamed and other colleagues.

There, they suggest that positive geometry is the underlying property of general QFTs.

If that was true, then, would all possible theories (including all possible QFTs and all possible theories of everything proposed so far) emerge from positive geometric constructions?

Comment: Please stop making trivial edits to bump the question into the front page. Thanks.

Comment: Echoing AFT's comment above: Stop making trivial edits just to bump the question - you have made 12 edits so far, none of which has been substantial. I have locked the question for a day to prevent further edits, it will be locked for longer if you continue this behaviour after the lock expires.