# All possible models to explain the hierarchy problem?

Tags: forces, particle-physics, universe, laws-of-physics, fine-tuning

There is an interesting paper by Arkani-Hamed and collaborators (https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06821) to address the hierarchy problem.

There, they consider many possible models of fundamental particle physics where they all have an exact copy of the Standard Model but with different Higgs masses.

However, they indicate that this assumption is done for simplicity, but that we could relax these assumptions and consider models with greater differences

At the beginning, they say:

> The first step is to introduce N sectors which are mutually non-interacting. The detailed particle content of these sectors is unimportant, with the exception that the Standard Model (SM) should not be atypical; many sectors should contain scalars, chiral fermions, unbroken gauge groups, etc. For simplicity, we imagine that they are exact copies of the SM, with the same gauge and Yukawa structure.

And at the end:

> However, it is easy to imagine a broader class of theories that realizes the same mechanism. We can relax the assumption that the Higgs masses are uniformly spaced (or even pulled from a uniformly distribution) or that all the new sectors are exact copies of the SM. It is also possible to construct different models of reheating, with new physics near the weak scale to modify the UV behavior of the theory.

All of this made me wonder: Are they saying that we could relax the assumptions of the model so that it would even include all possible UV theories (meaning all possible "microscopic" or "high-energy" physics, such as the different theories of quantum gravity and theories of everything proposed so far)?

Comment: You have already been asked [on a different question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778609/every-possible-qft-from-positive-geometry#comment1749932_778609) to avoid making trivial edits to your question. In case it was not obvious: This applies generally to *all* questions, also this one. The last two edits to this question have not improved the question in *any* way, please stop making these edits that just bump the question in the active queue without there having been meaningful activity. If you want to increase the visibility of your questions, that's what bounties are for.